# Delegate not being called in Swift

Tags: swift3, delegation

I can't figure out why my Delegate is not being called.
Here is where I define the protocol and call the delegate:

```
protocol CommentRatingViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func didCommentOrRatePost(updatedRating: Bool, addedComment:Bool)
}
class CommentRatingViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    weak var delegate:CommentRatingViewControllerDelegate?
...

@IBAction func saveRatingComment(_ sender: Any) {
        var updatedRating = false
        var addedComment = false
        rating = ratingView.rating
        if rating != 0.0 {
            saveRating(articleID: post.articleID, userID: post.userID)
            updatedRating = true
        }
        if commentsTextView.text != "" {
        saveComment(articleID: post.articleID, userID: post.userID, comment: commentsTextView.text!)
        addedComment = true
    }
    self.delegate?.didCommentOrRatePost(updatedRating: updatedRating, addedComment: addedComment)
    close()
}
```

....
And here is where conform to the delegate protocol:

```
extension PostDetailViewController: CommentRatingViewControllerDelegate {
    func didCommentOrRatePost(updatedRating: Bool, addedComment: Bool) {
        if updatedRating == true || addedComment == true {
            networkingState = .searching
            if updatedRating {
                getRating(articleID: post.articleID)
            }
            if addedComment {
                post.numberOfComments += post.numberOfComments
            }
            networkingState = .finishedSearching
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a breaking point when you invoke the delegate, is it nil ? (self.delegate)

Comment: I put a break after this line:self.delegate?.didCommentOrRatePost(updatedRating: updatedRating, addedComment: addedComment)
It is nil at this point.

Comment: Put a breaking point before you invoke self.delegate and check if it's nil, if it's nil then you didn't assign a strong ref to the weak ref (self.delegate). Also, show us the code when you assign the delegate a ref

Comment: Where do you **set** the delegate?

Comment: Yes it is nil.  I'm afraid I don't understand your point though?

Comment: If it's nil it means you didn't set the delegate. The delegate won't magically get an auto assign. You need to tell it where to point

Comment: @vadian In my extension.  I declare PostDetailViewController conforms to the Delegate protocol.  No?

Comment: I'm sorry gents I'm not following.  In the class definition (extension) I declare that that class is a delegate like so:
extension PostDetailViewController: CommentRatingViewControllerDelegate {

Comment: No, declaring the variable (as optional) sets it to `nil`, nothing else. You have to set the variable to the reference to the controller which adopts the protocol.

Comment: Took a walk, and it finally occurred to me what you all had been trying to explain.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you conform to a protocol, if you want to call delegate methods, it is not enough to make your class conform to the protocol, you also need to set the delegate to `self` inside the class.

```
class CommentRatingViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes.. I finally understand now.  Thanks!

Comment: No worries. If you found my answer useful, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Sorry.. thought I did!